# Hide certain filter from layered navigation top category

Tags: magento-1, layered-navigation

I have the following question:

Add the **layerend navigation** of a top category, all the filters of all underlying subcategories are shown. In top categories, we only want to show two filters: `product type and brand`.

We experimented in `view.phtml` based on other topics, but haven't found the exact result.

It would be great if you could point us towards the solution!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understood from your question. You want to remove category filter for your two top categories (for them, `isAnchor` is set to `Yes`) and keep all other filters as it is.

To achieve this, most easiest solution is a category specific layout update via any of your layout update xml file. For example, your category id be `12`. Then add below code in your `local.xml` file.

File : `app\design\frontend\[package]\[theme]\layout\local.xml`

```
<layout>
    <CATEGORY_12> 
        <reference name="catalog.leftnav">  
        <action method="unsetChild"><alias>category_filter</alias></action>
        </reference>
    </CATEGORY_12>
</layout>
```

Here `CATEGORY_12` is a layout handle update which is specifically created for a category with an id 12. Inside that, we are basically removing category filter from layered navigation.

Hope you get the idea.

### EDIT

So you want to remove category filter and keep all other filters intact. To do that, I believe you need to rewrite the class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View` which you can find at `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php`

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $stateBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_stateBlockName)
        ->setLayer($this->getLayer());

    $categoryBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_categoryBlockName)
        ->setLayer($this->getLayer())
        ->init();

    $this->setChild('layer_state', $stateBlock);
    $this->setChild('category_filter', $categoryBlock);

    //CATEGORY IDS IN WHICH YOU WANT TO HIDE OTHER FILTERS
    $excludeCategories = array(12, 13); //example
    $currentCategory   = Mage::registry('current_category');

    //avoid rendering attribute filters for exclude categories
    if (!in_array($currentCategory->getId(), $excludeCategories)) {
        $filterableAttributes = $this->_getFilterableAttributes();
        foreach ($filterableAttributes as $attribute) {
            if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'price') {
                $filterBlockName = $this->_priceFilterBlockName;
            } elseif ($attribute->getBackendType() == 'decimal') {
                $filterBlockName = $this->_decimalFilterBlockName;
            } else {
                $filterBlockName = $this->_attributeFilterBlockName;
            }

            $this->setChild($attribute->getAttributeCode() . '_filter',
                $this->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)
                    ->setLayer($this->getLayer())
                    ->setAttributeModel($attribute)
                    ->init());
        }
    }

    $this->getLayer()->apply();

    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

Use your category ids in `$excludeCategories` and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks Rajeev! That's indeed what I'm aiming for. Is category_12 the ID for the category itself, or the ID for the specific filter I want to remove?

Comment: We're getting there. When I input the category ID in the XML, the two basic filters are hidden (manufacturer, price). But I want the exact opposite: hiding the filters that are loaded from all underlying subcategories. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edit: I tried filter id + _filter (e.g. 186_filter) as an alias in the code: <CATEGORY_12> 
        <reference name="catalog.leftnav">  
        <action method="unsetChild"><alias>186_filter</alias></action>
        </reference>
    </CATEGORY_12> 

This does not hide filter id 186 on the page for category 12.. Am I missing something?

Comment: the code above will remove category filter only. not any other filters. but it will be removed if and only if `isAnchor` is set to `Yes` for the category. and the third comment wont work because it has no meaning at all.

Comment: Thanks Rajeev. 

We don't want to hide category_filters, but all the other filters in the topcategory. In subcategories every filter applied in backend can be visible. 

Next move: custom code in /public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml 

What I'm trying to accomplish is the following:
 
IF it's a subcategory, THEN output filters for the subcategory are as configured in the backend
IF it's NOT a subcategory, THEN only show category_filters

Comment: In line 51 we've added this so far:
                                      <?php $_isSubCategory=true; ?>
                                        <?php if ($_isSubCategory) { ?>
                                            <?php if($this->__($_filter->getName() ==  'Categories') { ?> 
                                                <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                                                <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
                                      <?php } ?>

Comment: @InlOM see my edit.